# What is the difference between "VC++" and "C++"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Someone asked me how familiar I am with VC++ and how familiar I am with C++.  What is the difference?

Comment: In addition to the excellent answers below, (and possibly off-topic) bear in mind that knowing how to code C++ (as in standard C++) is hardly the same as knowing how to code a windows app in C++.  Knowing how to code C++ is a subset of coding Windows apps in C++.

Comment: @YuHao normally you mark the newer question as a duplicate of the older one...

Answer (score 75, accepted):

C++ is the actual language, VC++ is Microsoft's Visual C++, an IDE for C++ development.

From [stason.org](http://stason.org/TULARC/webmaster/lang/c-cpp-faq/20-What-is-the-difference-between-C-and-Visual-C.html):

> C++ is the programming language, Visual C++ is Microsoft's implementation of it.
>
> When people talk about learning Visual C++, it usually has more to do with learning how to use the programming environment, and how to use the Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFCs) for Windows rather than any language issues. Visual C++ can and will compile straight C and C++.

Comment: Though it seems one cannot download this IDE. It comes as a so-called module in visual studio. Note microsoft itself uses the term "visual c++" as a language, implicitly referring to their custom extensions to c++ and c++/CLI.

Comment: @jiggunjer Exactly. People generally fall for this misconception.

Answer (score 22):

C++ is the name of a programming language that has been approved by international standards committees (ANSI/ISO).

VC++ (“Visual C++”) is the product name of Microsoft's C++ compiler and sometimes, but not officially, the IDE it's shipped with (“Visual Studio”).

Answer (score 7):

Well, Visual C++ used to stand for the Microsoft C++ compiler plus the MFC library. Basically there's no difference in the language itself, but VC++ includes a library, and some IDE support, for easily building GUIs.

Answer (score 5):

vc++ is a development environment and c++ is a language

Answer (score 4):

VC++ means different things to different people. You can use the Visual Studio environment to build (almost) standard C++ applications. You can also use it for Micrososft-specific additions - which vary from version to version. For example, the MFC components for windows applications, or the newer C++/CLI for .NET applications

Answer (score 3):

VC++ is short for Visual C++, and is an IDE (integrated development environment) developed by Microsoft, included as part of Visual Studio.  C++ is a language.

Answer (score 3):

C++ is a language, VC++ (Visual C++) is a Microsoft development environment which was a forerunner to Visual Studio which helps you write C++.

You can know everything there is to know about C++ and never have seen VC++.

Answer (score 3):

VC++ is IDE developed by Microsoft using microsoft c++ compiler.while C++ is the programming language.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, they refer to its corresponding **C++** implementation and its compilers.

> **C++** refers to standard headers/functions and its **GCC C++** compiler.
>
> **VC++** refers to Microsoft implementation of **C++** standard and its **VC++**
>   compiler.

They are not compatible with each other. Linux network/threading functions, numeric data types are different than its Windows counterpart. You can't compile Linux **C++** code directly in Windows without using third-party GCC ports such as Cygwin/MinGW.

Most academic/research tools and libraries are written in **C++ (GCC)**, and one will have the hard time to compile those in **VC++**.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ and C++ are two entirely different things. They are related, though.

C++ is a high-level programming language that a compiler translates into machine code a computer can understand and execute.

Visual C++ is a tool created by Microsoft to make writing, compiling and debugging C++ source code easier. Visual C++ is an Integrated Development Environment (IDE).

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/172353/